# Did Sawyer really fire Jill at the ending or was she joking?

Tags: ending, unsane

I know this is not the most important question that you should have after watching the film **Unsane (2018)** but I just can't get it off my head.

At the ending of the film you see Sawyer eating salad with her co-worker Jill. Then out of nowhere she says it's time of her to move on and clear out her desk.

**Did she really fire her? Or was she just joking?**

The movie is so dark in tone, I just can't it make out.

Answer (score 1):

[Yes, she fired her](https://screenrant.com/unsane-movie-ending-explained/2/):

> The final scene of Unsane cuts to six months later, when the now-freed
>   Sawyer is having a chilly lunch with her co-worker, Jill (Sarah
>   Stiles). **Sawyer has since received a big promotion, and uses her
>   newfound power to fire Jill over their salads.**

Comment: Why did she fire her? Was it because she did not like her?